# ElasticSearch Query with only partial term returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, bower

I am searching Elasticsearch through javascript, mainly just doing a very simple trending analysis.  What I want to see is which country across the world has the most hamburgers sold.  The problem is instead of seeing United States, United Kingdom returned, I get "united" as a result since that term is obviously occuring with both of those results.  How do i query to return the full country name?  Not just states, or united?

My data doing a plain search in ES looks like:

```
"country": "United States",
"place_name": "United States",
"hSold": "27",
```

My query in JS:

```
esClient.search({
        index: 'burgers',
        size: 20,
        body: {
            // Begin query.
            query: {
                "match_all" : {}               
            },
            // Aggregate on the results
            facets: {
                  tagcloud: {
                    terms: {
                      field: 'country', 'size': 20                       
                    }
                  }
                }
            // End query.
        }
```

The results i see back:

```
United: 1047
States: 987
south: 870
kingdom: 600
```

I should have results like United States, not united.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `"index":"not_analyzed"` in your `"country"` field in your mapping. It's worth spending some time investigating how [analysis](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) works in Elasticsearch, but the basic idea is that if you do not specify an analyzer in your mapping definition, Elasticsearch will use the default [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which will create a lower-case token for each word in the field.

As a more concrete example, I could set up an index like this (I'm using the "Sense" syntax; I assume you can translate it into the JavaScript you need):

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "country": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "place_name": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "h_sold": {
               "type": "integer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

then add a couple of documents:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "country": "United States",
   "place_name": "United States",
   "hSold": 27
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
   "country": "United Kingdom",
   "place_name": "United Kingdom",
   "hSold": 25
}
```

Then I can use a [terms aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `"country"` field:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
       "countries": {
          "terms": {
             "field": "country",
             "size": 10
          }
       }
    }
}
```

which gives me back the results I expect:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "countries": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "United Kingdom",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "United States",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

(you can use facets instead of aggregations, though facets are deprecated.)

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/dbbcc9f8298e82e6043a0636ff9742c2e11f107f

Comment: Thanks for this.  Great answer, in case anyone else is looking at a similar problem this helps too: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html